# MVC- Count Number of Records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

**Edit** My view is using the Employer model. Employer and JobPosting have a 1:M relationship. I will share more of the view for context.

**Context**: In my application, I want to show the Employer the number of applicants who applied for their JobPosting. The code that I currently have written is not returning any value. It's not throwing any errors- but it's not working either. I'm pretty sure the issue is in my controller, but I'll provide the Model and View as well.

### Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AppCount()
        {
            foreach (var app in db.JobPostings.ToList())
            {
                int id = app.JobPostingID;
                int count= db.Applications.Where(a => a.JobPostingID == id).Count();
                app.AppCount = count;
                ViewBag.AppCount = count;
            }
            return View();
 }
```

### View:

```
  @model InTurn_Model.Employer
.
.
.
        <h2>My Job Postings</h2>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "JobPostings", null, null)
        </p>
        <div id="employeeContainer"></div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
        
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Job Type</th>
                <th>Number of Applicatiosn</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        
            @foreach (var item in Model.JobPostings)
            {
                if (item.EmployerID == Model.EmployerID)
                {
                    <tr>
        
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Position)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.JobType)
                        </td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.AppCount</td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "JobPostings", new { id = item.JobPostingID }, null) </td>
        
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
```

### Model:

```
  [MetadataType(typeof(JobPostingMetaData))]
    public partial class JobPosting
    {
        public int AppCount { get; set; }
        private sealed class JobPostingMetaData
        {
            [Display(Name = "Job Posting ID")]
            public int JobPostingID { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Employer ID")]
            public int EmployerID { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Description")]
            public string Desc { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
            public JobType JobType { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Employment Type")]
            public TimeType TimeType { get; set; }
            [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
            public decimal Wage { get; set; }

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking this. I just needed to set this up from the JobPosting model, and then the rest worked, I didn't need to iterate through the Controller at all.

```
 public int AppCount => Applications.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that I see.

First, you are not passing `Model` from controller to view. However, you are iterating through `Model.JobPostings`. It is empty.

Second, you assign `ViewBag.AppCount` in the loop. So, all values, except for the last one are lost. But if you fix the first problem (use `Model` instead of `ViewBag`) - the second might go away by itself.

Comment: Oh! I probably should have shared more of the view.

I am using the @Model Namespace.Employer model in the view. I was only showing partial code, where the count is expected to show. 

The Employer table is linked to the JobPosting table through a 1:M relationship. So it is iterating through the JobPosting list.

Comment: even so, you are not passing the model, as indicated in another answer!

Comment: Ok!

I think I see what you're saying. Sorry, I'm very new to this. I've only really been working with MVC on a per semester basis in class, and this is the first app I'm building from the ground up.

So instead of ViewBag...should I try something like @HtmlDisplayFor(model=>item.AppCount) ?

item refers to the JobPosting model I believe, so that should get me something, right?

Comment: that's one way to do it... usually you have a variable on both sides of lambda expression; otherwise, what is `item`? Anyway, the first problem is that you don't pass model into the view. Once you do, you can try simpler expressions (without lambda) to get comfortable with code in the view

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the model in the view with @model:

```
@model YourNameSpace.JobPosting
```

Then return that model to the view:

```
 public ActionResult AppCount()
        {
            foreach (var app in db.JobPostings.ToList())
            {
                int id = app.JobPostingID;
                int count= db.Applications.Where(a => a.JobPostingID == id).Count();
                app.AppCount = count;
                ViewBag.AppCount = count;
            }
            return View(app);
 }
```

This will make the values in the model available to the view. There is no need to use ViewBag, as AppCount is part of the model.